# Is there a place to store luggage at Phoenix Mills?

Tags: luggage-storage, mumbai

Is there a place to store luggage (a stroller) at [Phoenix Mills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Street_Phoenix) for a couple of hours?

Comment: I take it from the tags this mall is in Mumbai?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TSE. Firstly, what do you mean by "A stroller for a couple of hours."? Also, regarding what CMaster asked you, please specify exactly which mall you are talking about (where it is, etc.) You can use the "edit" button to clarify the post. If you do this, your question can be answered.

Comment: You can use "Hands free" of any shop for that.